# WooCommerce custom payment gateway is not showing in checkout

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, payment-gateway, payment-method

I am trying to use a WooCommerce Custom payment gateway plugin. I added the details needed to show the plugin in the dashboard.
I have tried another plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wc-gateway-cib, but it is not showing in checkout page either.

```
<?php

/**
 * Plugin Name: Noob Payment for Woocommerce
 * Plugin URI: https://omukiguy.com
 * Author Name: Laurence Bahiirwa
 * Author URI: https://omukiguy.com
 * Description: This plugin allows for local content payment systems.
 * Version: 0.1.0
 * License: 0.1.0
 * License URL: http://www.gnu.org/licenses/gpl-2.0.txt
 * text-domain: noob-pay-woo
*/ 

if ( ! in_array( 'woocommerce/woocommerce.php', apply_filters( 'active_plugins', get_option( 'active_plugins' ) ) ) ) return;

add_action( 'plugins_loaded', 'noob_payment_init', 11 );

function noob_payment_init() {
    if( class_exists( 'WC_Payment_Gateway' ) ) {
        class WC_Noob_pay_Gateway extends WC_Payment_Gateway {
            public function __construct() {
                $this->id   = 'noob_payment';
                $this->icon = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_noob_icon', plugins_url('/assets/icon.png', __FILE__ ) );
                $this->has_fields = false;
                $this->method_title = __( 'Noob Payment', 'noob-pay-woo');
                $this->method_description = __( 'Noob local content payment systems.', 'noob-pay-woo');

                $this->title = $this->get_option( 'title' );
                $this->description = $this->get_option( 'description' );
                $this->instructions = $this->get_option( 'instructions', $this->description );

                $this->init_form_fields();
                $this->init_settings();

                add_action( 'woocommerce_update_options_payment_gateways_' . $this->id, array( $this, 'process_admin_options' ) );

            }

            public function init_form_fields() {
                $this->form_fields = apply_filters( 'woo_noob_pay_fields', array(
                    'enabled' => array(
                        'title' => __( 'Enable/Disable', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'type' => 'checkbox',
                        'label' => __( 'Enable or Disable Noob Payments', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'default' => 'no'
                    ),
                    'title' => array(
                        'title' => __( 'Noob Payments Gateway', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'type' => 'text',
                        'default' => __( 'Noob Payments Gateway', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'desc_tip' => true,
                        'description' => __( 'Add a new title for the Noob Payments Gateway that customers will see when they are in the checkout page.', 'noob-pay-woo')
                    ),
                    'description' => array(
                        'title' => __( 'Noob Payments Gateway Description', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'default' => __( 'Please remit your payment to the shop to allow for the delivery to be made', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'desc_tip' => true,
                        'description' => __( 'Add a new title for the Noob Payments Gateway that customers will see when they are in the checkout page.', 'noob-pay-woo')
                    ),
                    'instructions' => array(
                        'title' => __( 'Instructions', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'type' => 'textarea',
                        'default' => __( 'Default instructions', 'noob-pay-woo'),
                        'desc_tip' => true,
                        'description' => __( 'Instructions that will be added to the thank you page and odrer email', 'noob-pay-woo')
                    ),
                    
                ));
            }

            public function process_payments( $order_id ) {
                
            }

      
        }
    }
}

add_filter( 'woocommerce_payment_gateways', 'add_to_woo_noob_payment_gateway');

function add_to_woo_noob_payment_gateway( $gateways ) {
    $gateways[] = 'WC_Noob_pay_Gateway';
    return $gateways;
}
```

I already enabled the payment in woo-commerce setting-> payment, however it not showing in the checkout out page
[image]
WordPress version is 4.6.2

Answer (score 0):

checkout https://wordpress.org/support/topic/payment-gateway-bug-urgent-version-8-3-1/, It seems to be a problem with the checkout, I used an older version of wordpress (6.3) before working this out.